# Arch Linux installation on VMWare will not proceed

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I'm trying to install Arch Linux 2013.14.01 on VMWare Player, but after I select "Boot Arch Linux (i686)", it goes directly to:

```
archiso login: root (automatic login)
```

In the tutorials I've seen they go directly to the blue setup screen. Why isn't that happening for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no more "blue screen", the original arch installation UI have been removed for a while,

Instead, use `pacstrap` to install to a chrooted environment, and setup grub / fstab afterwards.

[See this link for detail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide)

Comment: Ok, understood. So with this current setup, I still need to partition my disk, right? I've been using Ubuntu for a long time but it's my first shot at Arch Linux. Perhaps absolute beginners should visit this page also. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_Guide But thanks for your help. You answered my question.

Comment: @d4ryl3 yep, pacstrap ist just like debstrap, only do the package installation stuff